# An example of a tensor product consisting of only simple tensors?

Tags: tensor-products, ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, modules

Hy guys. I'm doing some independent analysis which makes use of the tensor product of modules (over commutative rings with unit 1, and ring homomorphisms map $1 \mapsto 1$). Let $\pi: A' \to A$ be a surjective homomorphism of rings which identifies $A$ as an $A'$-algebra (and hence an $A'$-module). Let $M$ be any $A'$-module. The following analysis suggests that the tensor product $M \otimes_{A'} A$ consists entirely of simple tensors, but I am not sure that I am entirely convinced, and any feedback would be appreciated.

Let $m \otimes a$ be an arbitrary element of $M \otimes_{A'} A$. By the surjectivity of $\pi$, we can find an element $a' \in A'$ such that $\pi(a') = a$, so

$m \otimes a = m \otimes \pi(a') = a'(m \otimes 1) = a'm \otimes 1$.

Thus, if we have an arbitrary element $\sum_{i = 1}^n m_i \otimes a_i \in M \otimes_{A'} A$, we can choose pre-images $a_1',...,a_n'$ of the $a_i$ such that $ \sum_{i = 1}^n m_i \otimes a_i = (\sum_{i=1}^n a_i'm_i) \otimes 1 $, so every tensor is simple.

Comment: Take $A'$ a field, $M$ a vector space of dimension m, $A$ a vector space of dimension n given some ring structure (e.g. product ring). Then we can easily find m,n (I think if both are >1?) where there are non-simple tensors.

Comment: @David:  there won't be any interesting surjective maps from a field to another ring.  I think your argument is fine Chris, even if this question would be better suited to math.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your argument is right. In your situation, $A \cong A^{\prime} / I$ for some ideal $I$ of $A^{\prime}$, and the tensor product $M\otimes_{A^{\prime}} A$ is isomorphic to $M / \left(IM\right)$, where $IM$ is the submodule of $M$ spanned by all products of the form $im$ with $i\in I$ and $m\in M$. This explains why it consists of only simple tensors.

The isomorphism $M\otimes_{A^{\prime}} A \cong M / \left(IM\right)$ is actually pretty useful. Three years ago I asked on this site why people [state the Chinese Remainder Theorem only for rings, and not for modules](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/18959/chinese-remainder-theorem-for-rings-why-not-for-modules). Two people answered on the same day that the version for modules follows immediately from that for rings by the above-mentioned isomorphism.

This is indeed better suited to math.stackexchange.com, as was my question. :)

Comment: Thank you. I will keep in mind the distinction between math.stackexchange.com and mathoverflow.net for future questions.